# Visual Studio automatic build increment when content files change

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm using the automatic build increment feature of Visual Studio/MSBuild in my AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Haven't really found any documentation describing this behavior but from my experience, whenever I change a code file (for example a Controller in an MVC project or any other *.cs file), the assembly number is incremented after building the project.

But not if I make a change in a View, JavaScript or CSS file...the assembly version stays the same. Is it possible to tell Visual Studio to trigger the version change in these cases too ?

I want to rely on the assembly version in my continuous integration process, so I want to make sure that when a change is made in my project, the assembly version would change (when the CI server builds the project). If there is no change, the version should stay the same.

If there is another approach to achieve this instead of using the automatic build increment feature, it would also be good. I haven't found any so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it was not to use the assembly version at all.

Instead I have written a simple console app which creates a hash based on the name and the contents of all the files from the project.

The console app is executed by the CI server and the hash is written to a file.

Upon next build the new hash is compared to the one in the file and if it is different, it means that the project has changed and the build number has to be incremented.